# Ghost blog is only accessible with www

Tags: ssl-certificate, digital-ocean, ghost-blog

I have a Ghost blog hosted on digitalocean, my domain can only be accessible with a secure connection (it's a `.dev` site).

My site is available when I access it with `www`, e.g. [www.androidoss.dev](http://www.androidoss.dev), but not when accessed directly as androidoss.dev.

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have deployed the Ghost on the DigitalOcean server then it's running behind the Nginx probably. So during the Ghost installation there a command is executed which is `ghost setup nginx` which setup Nginx for you and then run `ghost setup ssl` which set up Let's Encrypt SSL for the provided domain name and it doesn't create a redirection rule from `non-www` to `www`.

So you can do this by adding a redirection URI in your Nginx file.

You have to add these lines in the server block for `http`. It will look like this and the file-path is `/etc/nginx/sites-available/ww.example.com`

```
server {
    listen       80;
   ...................
   ...................
}
```

you have to add the below lines at the place of dotted lines.

```
server_name  example.com www.example.com;
return       301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
```